# Online dead link alert service

Tags: links, automation, service, dead-links, reporting

I'm looking for an online service that will periodically (daily) check for broken links on my site (~100 pages). I see lots of tools that you can download and run, and indeed have used such tools in the past. But this seems like an obvious task for an online service: sign up, tell it my URL, then it would only email me if there are more broken links today than there were yesterday.

My organisation's web site is not our major focus, and it's only a small part of my job. Hence the need to completely automate tasks where possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web apps that offer scheduled link checking with emailed test results:

- [Nodeworks](http://www.nodeworks.com/)
- [No tags, no glory!](http://www.notagsnoglory.com/)
- [LinkAlarm](http://www.linkalarm.com/)

All offer free trial versions or limited accounts with paid upgrade options.

The W3C offers a [free online link checker tool,](http://validator.w3.org/checklink) the source code for which is [available here,](http://search.cpan.org/dist/W3C-LinkChecker/) but this isn't an automated service -- you'd have to run the link checker manually yourself for each page (or for each unique design template that your site uses).

Comment: These look like exactly what I was looking for. My observations so far:
 * Nodeworks: free up to 250 pages, daily runs. $15/5000 links.
 * No tags, no glory: free up to 1000 pages, manual runs (maybe automatic with $$$) $30/mo
 * LinkAlarm: free up to 14 days, 100 pages, weekly runs. Costs $0.01/page.

I love the different units in all their pricing and free options (per page/day/link...)