# 404 monitoring tool for websites?

Tags: tools, 404

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Online dead link alert service](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14010/online-dead-link-alert-service)

Is there a tool to monitor or discover 404's or broken links online?

Google Webmaster 404 tool is a bit slow.

I'd like to discover the 404's before Google Webmaster does.

Edit: I use linux and i'm looking for online tools for 404 discovery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Xenu's Link Sleuth](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html) works very well and is free. The website looks crappy, but the software works well. :)

Comment: There any online tools? I use linux.

Answer (score 1):

Make a customized 404 page and insert the tracking code for Google Analytics. You can then track what kind of address is being typed by visitors who get 404.

Comment: you can track 404 status and loading time for pages using google spreadsheet. Google sheets come with lots of functionality including scripts and triggers that make these kinds of task very easy.